# Can you put whole eggs in a blender?

Tags: eggs, blender, scrambled-eggs

So, a bit of an odd question, but it's been bugging me for a while; could you put whole eggs (shell and all) into a blender if you're making something like scrambled eggs?  In a sufficiently powerful blender, would the shell bits damage the blender at all?  What about your digestive tract?  Is there anything in egg shells that could nutritionally help/harm you?  I know it only takes 5 seconds to crack eggs, but I'm curious.

Comment: I believe there are commercial egg-cracking machines that work something like this. They remove the shells via a centrifuge and strainer, and you end up with eggs ready for scrambling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the blender should not be damaged by the shells; if it is, it should have been replaced anyway. The mass of the shells is simply not enough to damage the blender in any significant way.

I would not, however, recommend eating the product, for a few reasons:

1. You cannot be confident that the egg shell has been completely pulverised. At some point, the blades stop chopping the shell, and simply spins it around
2. Whenever using egg shells for presentation, they should be thoroughly cleaned and sterilized, because you don't know what is coating it. You may very conceivably contract diseases from bacteria on the shell.

Comment: With regards to point 1, what's wrong with not completely pulverizing the shell?  I'd guess any bits remaining would be very small, so what would the problem be?  Would they cut up your digestive tract or something?  Or just ruin the texture/mouthfeel of the eggs?

Comment: @chaosentity They would absolutely ruin the texture - they probably won't be that small, so it'll be like eating eggs full of tiny rocks or sand. What you actually would want to do is blend it so they're not totally pulverized, so you can strain them out (or let them fall to the bottom and waste a bit of egg).

Comment: You might of course use a sieve to remove the pieces of shell, but the safety concerns would remain.

Answer (score 2):

Before cholesterol became an issue for me I did this all the time.  No harm to the blender nor, barring cholesterol, to me.  I did get a small amount of shell dregs at the bottom of the cup (almost a sand consistency).

Just be sure to wash the egg before tossing it into the blender :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way the bakeries the prisons do it. They put all their eggs into an industrial mixer, mix them and strain the shells out.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  You are answering a question which is over 9 years old.  When answering old questions, it's only useful if your answer supplies unique, new information not already in the answer pool.  Unfortunately, your answer is not strong, lacking references and detail.